# Need help identifying encoding format for this received data from a websocket

Tags: websocket, binary, hex

I have this encoded string from a websocket server that I am requesting data from; I'm not sure what encoding it has returned to me. Can anybody help me?

```
\xf6@\xbbx\xa2\xe7\x8c\xbbW\xf7\xce\x01\xd0\x91T\xf2\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x92:h[\xcb}o
```

I've tried converting it with python, and it didn't work. I also tried ChatGPT but I doubt it worked; and it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
|F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
|I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
|N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
| |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
|                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
+-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
:                     Payload Data continued ...                :
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|                     Payload Data continued ...                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When you get the data from the websocket server,
the first byte is:

- 1 FIN
- 0 RSV1
- 0 RSV2
- 0 RSV3

and the opcode ( the second 4 bits ) for the data type

- 0000 denotes a continuation frame
- 0001 denotes a text frame
- ...

the second bytes :

the first bit is the Mask and the rest ( 7 bits, 7+16 bits, or 7+64 bits) is the Payload length

here is the RFC 6455 if you want to read more,
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455